# Why am I getting a syntax error on my sqlite call?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

Error:

```
01-23 20:26:11.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1324): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "from": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE Transactions ( _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, type TEXT NOT NULL, part TEXT NOT NULL, time TEXT NOT NULL, from INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', to INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', Machine_Id TEXT NOT NULL, DNI TEXT NOT NULL, quantity INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' )
```

I have used similar code before, but this error evades me. Usually it has to do with spacing or apostrophes...

Thanks!

Comment: `from` is reserved word in sqlite https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html

Comment: i note two things may be problem first using from it key word in sql , second using '0' instead of 0 for integer value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename your column name to something different than `from` in your table creation. 
You cannot use 'from' as column name https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html